# Stretching TextBlock between two images on a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two stacked buttons, the top button has images on the left and right of the TextBlock. The bottom button has one image to the left with a TextBlock on the right. It is desired to have the TextBlock on the top button centered and stretched to fill the space between the two images. How can this be done?

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="2"
            Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Tb}"
            Click="Button1_Click">
            <!---->
            <DockPanel>
                <Image 
                    Source="/images/block_arrow_left.png"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" 
                    Margin="0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="Tb"
                    Padding="5"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontSize="14"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="button1"/>
                <Image 
                    Source="/images/block_arrow_left.png"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" 
                    Margin="0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                </Image>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="2"
            Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Tb}"
            Click="Button2_Click">
            <DockPanel>
                <Image 
                    Source="images/block_arrow_left.png"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" >
                </Image>
                <TextBlock 
                    Padding="5"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontSize="14"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="button22222222222222">
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `DockPanel` with a `Grid`, give the `Grid` three columns, place your `TextBlock` in the center column and set the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Stretch`:

```
<Button 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="2"
    Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Tb}"
    Click="Button1_Click">
    <!---->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image 
            Source="/images/block_arrow_left.png"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </Image>
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="Tb"
            Padding="5"
            Grid.Column="1"
            FontSize="14"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="button1"/>
        <Image 
            Source="/images/block_arrow_left.png"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Tb}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. Works now. Your change needs posted needs HorizontalAlignment changed from "Stretch" to "Center".

Comment: The change is needed in the TextBlock.

Comment: @namg_engr I took your question to mean you wanted it centered vertically and stretched horizontally on account of your question stating: 'stretched to fill the space between the two images'

Comment: Yes, my original problem statement wasn't clear in regards to centering. Thanks again for your help.